# Javascript and XML - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xml

I'm trying to create a web application that pulls from an XML file and displays the information in a table. The XML file that I have is generated from a PHP script. The problem I'm having is that the data doesn't show up in the table, and when I checked the google chrome development console, it said I had the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined on
>   line 37.

Here's the code that I'm trying to work with

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
th, td {
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="init()">

<script>
function init(){
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
  else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://hankyranky.com/dev/includes/reviewxml.gen.php?bathroomid=1",false);
  xmlhttp.send();
  xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;

  document.write("<table><tr><th>Artist</th><th>Title</th></tr>");
  var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("review");
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
    {
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("bathroomid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("rating")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td></tr>");
    }
  document.write("</table>");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here's the output for the XML file:

```
<ratings>
  <rating>
    <id>1</id>
    <bathroomid>1</bathroomid>
    <review>5</review>
  </rating>
  <rating>
    <id>2</id>
    <bathroomid>1</bathroomid>
    <review>4</review>
  </rating>
</ratings>
```

And just in case anyone needs it, here is the code for the XML generator

```
<?php

require("db.config.php");

// Start XML file, create parent node

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<ratings/>');
$bathroomid = ($_GET['bathroomid']);

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server

$connection=mysql_connect ('localhost', $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {  die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());}

// Set the active MySQL database

$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
  die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the bathrooms table

$query = "SELECT * FROM ratings WHERE bathroomid = '".$bathroomid."'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
  die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $rating = $xml->addChild('rating');
  $rating->addChild('id', $row['id']);
  $rating->addChild('bathroomid', $row['bathroomid']);
  $rating->addChild('review', $row['rating']);
}



echo $xml->saveXML();

?>
```

Thanks everyone, really appreciate the help!

Comment: Looks like a job for XSLT… ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tags like `bathroomid` and `review` are children of `rating` element not of `review` element so `x[i].getElementsByTagName("bathroomid")` won't return any element.

Instead each of these are children of `rating` element, so iterate over that element like

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("rating");
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much, I'll mark it as answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me, so that'll be in about 8 minutes. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you mixed up the `rating` and `review` elements in your Javascript. The following code block:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("review");
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("bathroomid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("rating")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td></tr>");
}
```

Should be:

```
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("rating");
  for (i=0;i<x.length;i++) {
    document.write("<tr><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("bathroomid")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("review")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td></tr>");
}
```